# How to display just students in users page(Moodle:/admin/user.php)

Tags: moodle

I want to display just students in moodle users page without manually adding a filter using the web interface. Could anybody help me on how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a link that shows only students but you'll need to post the data. Here's how I did it.

If you install WebDeveloper - http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/

Then go to /admin/user.php and click WebDeveloper, choose the "Forms" tab and "convert POSTS to GETS".

Choose the filter and click add filter. This will display a url with all the form fields. Moodle is expecting a POST rather than a GET though.

So copy and paste the url into a variable and use the single_button function with the post method eg:

```
$url = '/admin/user.php?sesskey=xxxxxxx&_qf__user_add_filter_form=1&mform_showmore_id_newfilter=1&mform_isexpanded_id_newfilter=1&realname_op=0&realname=&lastname_op=0&lastname=&firstname_op=0&firstname=&email_op=0&email=&city_op=0&city=&country_op=0&confirmed=&suspended=&profile_fld=0&profile_op=0&profile=&courserole_rl=5&courserole_ct=0&courserole=&systemrole=0&cohort_op=2&cohort=&username_op=0&username=&auth=&deleted=&addfilter=Add+filter';
echo $OUTPUT->single_button($url, get_string('student'), 'post');
```

Copy and paste your own url rather than the above.

You can probably remove a lot of the parameters. You should also get the roleid for the student and use the moodle_url function, eg:

```
$studentroleid = $DB->get_field('role', 'id', array('shortname' => 'student'));
$params = array('courserole_rl' => $studentroleid, 'courserole_ct' => 0, ... );
$url = new moodle_url('/admin/user.php', $params);
echo $OUTPUT->single_button($url, get_string('students'), 'post');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as, in Moodle, it is rare for someone to be assigned the role of 'student' at the system level (and if you did, they would have access to every course on the site).

The concept of 'student' in Moodle only makes sense at the course level.

Comment: I think he is talking about the browse list of users - there is an option to filter for learner role under course role when you click "show more" - /admin/user.php